# Can we change the default description about the field that appears on hovering the field in vso?

Tags: tfs, field, azure-devops

i have 2 questions.

1. can we remove the default description(field name and type) of a field that appears on hovering the field ? After adding the description to the field, on hovering it some default text is displayed along with the description added.
2. can we add hyperlink in the desctiption of the field ?

Comment: default text -> field name and type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using VSTS (VSO), the answers for both questions are NO since you can only list WIT definitions but can’t change and import into VSTS.
- If you are using TFS, the answers are yes for both. You can use [witadmin](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits) to change a WIT.

  > With witadmin, you can modify XML definition files to support the
  >   On-premises XML process model. For Hosted XML and Inheritance process
  >   models, you can only use witadmin commands to list information.